# how to extract document size from FileNet oracle database

Tags: filenet-content-engine, filenet-ce-sql

I am new to FileNet. Is it possible for me to write a SQL statement to retrieve the file size of the document from FileNet oracle database ? What will be the field name be?

Comment: [Content Table](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/filenet-p8-platform/5.5.x?topic=reference-object-store-table-schemas#database_table_schemas__content_table)

Comment: Hi , which field will capture the filename ?

Comment: What is your effort so far? What have you tried?